# OpenTK separate thread for high FPS update

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, opentk, basic

I create a separate thread wherein I create GLControl (engineViewport) and loop:

Thread sub:

```
engineViewport = New OpenTK.GLControl()

Do Until engineViewport.Created = True
   Thread.Yield()
Loop

AddHandler engineViewport.Paint, AddressOf engineVievport_Paint    

Dim frameTickDurationMS As Long = 1000 / FPS
Dim frameTickTimeMS As New Stopwatch()
Dim prevTickTimeMS As Long = 0
frameTickTimeMS.Start()

Do
'some simple calculations here
'irrevelant to this situaltion

   Do While (frameTickTimeMS.ElapsedMilliseconds - prevTickTimeMS) < frameTickDurationMS 
      'wait for accurate time for rendering next frame / FPS based
      Thread.Yield()  
   Loop  

   'invalidate GLControl to render OpenGL frame 
   If engineViewport.IsIdle Then
      engineViewport.Invalidate()
   End If

   prevTickTimeMS = frameTickTimeMS.ElapsedMilliseconds
Loop
```

On same thread i do all the calculations and in Paint event I do all the GL stuff (not much, simple low polly, one texture, but it needs to refresh very quick).

Paint event sub:

```
Private Sub engineVievport_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs)
    'Clear Buffers
    GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit)
    GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit)

    'all GL stuff here
'

    engineViewport.SwapBuffers() 
End Sub
```

Works fine, but to some point (75FPS is about max), then UI starts to lag (do not respond in realtime to events).   Processor load is 10-12% total (even spread across cores) so this is not cpu bottelneck, GPU load is also 5-10%...  GLControl itself is fine (sucesffuly tested 120FPS), draws fluently.  Only UI is a problem.

As I suspect that all UI and Paint event works on the same thread, and that causes UI to get laggy.

Is there any way to push Paint event of GLControl to a separate process? Basicly make whole chain form Invalidate to Paint Event separate from main UI thread. I don't need PaintEventArgs so if it was possible i could send GL commands from thread where I created GLControl, but that do not work.

Comment: I would recommend using Application.Idle += yourEventHandler.

Comment: Or a Timer as your render loop.

Comment: I don't understand "timer as your render loop".  I use timer  (stopwatch) to invalidate GLControl as ofen as i neet it to redraw.  Then Paint event is raised and all GL commands are passed to GLControll, and SwapBuffers at the end show what OpenGL has draw.  I cannot replace "engineVievport.Invalidate()" with commands that are in Paint event. Nothing shows on GLControl.

Comment: engineViewport.Context.VSync = False   drasticly improved GUI response times (up to 110-120FPS).  No visible tearing, but I doubt that it's a valid solution.

Comment: @Krythic : For the record, event subscriptions are made by the [**`AddHandler` statement**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7taxzxka.aspx) in VB.NET. :)